# Process Builder Cannot Reference Related Object Name in Criteria

Tags: process-builder

So this is a really strange Process Builder bug that seems unavoidable, wondering if I'm missing anything.

I have a process with criteria that references the name of a related object:

`[User_Account__c].Service_Profile.Name = "Admin"`

The idea is that when the name of this object (related by lookup field) is set to "Admin", a record update will fire. Simple, right? Not really. When the record is updated this message is received:

`"The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Service_Profile__c.Name because it hasn't been set or assigned."`

So, it acts like it is running before update, and doesn't have a value to reference. That would seem odd enough, since basic workflow rules could do this, and yet it gets stranger. If I change the criteria to reference an even further removed object:

`[User_Account__c].Service_Profile.Service.Name`

..then it fires and updates just fine. So clearly it has a value that it can access.

Now, I change the criteria yet again, to this:

`AND(
ISCHANGED([User_Account__c].Service_Profile__c), 
[User_Account__c].Service_Profile__c.Name = "Admin")`

THEN the update will also fire, but if delete the value from Service_Profile__c and save, then I get the same "The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Service_Profile__c.Name because it hasn't been set or assigned." message again!

Any idea what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE; it is worth noting that you can use [edit] to make your question more readable - specifically, by using back quotes around code fragments (e.g. `my code`) to make them stand out. I did this for one of these so you can see how it is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out with some help eventually, the needed criteria looks like this:

```
AND(
      ISCHANGED([User_Account__c].Service_Profile__c),
      NOT(ISBLANK([User_Account__c].Service_Profile__c)),
      [User_Account__c].Service_Profile__c.Name = "Admin"
      )
```

Basically, needed to add some criteria that would stop the process from referencing [User_Account__c].Service_Profile__c.Name when [User_Account__c].Service_Profile__c was going to be null in the equivalent of Trigger.new.

Comment: Your org doesn't have any profiles named "Admin".

Comment: Ha, it's almost as if you have insider information about my org...then again the formula isn't referencing an actual profile now, is it?